# Materialize in Angular 10 - CSS being applied, but JS not executing

Tags: angular, materialize

I am new to Angular and Materialize. I am trying to initialize a carousel within my Angular component.

I've installed Materialize-css and have css and js in angular.json.

The CSS works perfectly, but the js doesn't work, including modals, carousel, etc. A sidenav worked adding `M.AutoInit()` in index.js.

This is the component.html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col l4 m6 s12" *ngFor="let field of fields">
    <div class="carousel">
      <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img [src]="'http://localhost:3000/'+field.imagePath"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
    var instances = M.Carousel.init(elems);
  });
</script>
```

This is the component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import { FieldService } from '../../services/field.service'

declare const M: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})

export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  fields= [];

  constructor(
    private fieldService: FieldService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    M.AutoInit();
    this.fieldService.getFields()
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(res)
          this.fields = res;
        },
        err => console.log(err))
  }
}
```

I tried declaring const M as any and adding M.AutoInit() in ngOnInit but still not working.

Comment: I'm curious you say "I've installed Materialize-css", but have you installed the Materialize JS file as well? Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes, I've installed Materialize with `npm install materialize-css --save`, then I added the CSS and JS in angular.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TH JS isue was resolved replacing `declare const M: any;` with `impoert* as M from 'materialize.css/js/materialize.min.js` but the carousel stiil didin't work.

Answer (score 0):

you must add the materialize js script on angular.json.

```
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js"
            ]
```